# Check if url matches template

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching

I'm working on a routing system for PHP (language is irreverent to the question).

I have an array of routes like this: (in the actual program each route has a callback that is run if it matches)

```
[
    '/',
    '/posts/{id}',
    '/posts/{year}/{month}',
   '/about'
]
```

What is the best way I can take a URL, say `/posts/2b45v21` and get the closest matching route from the array?

Given the input `/posts/2b45v21`, it should match `/posts/{id}` but not `/` or `/posts/{year}/{month}`.

I tried a few ways with regex, like converting the `{...}` to `.*?` and then escaping all the backslashes, but I couldn't one that wouldn't match `/`.

I assume that the best way would be to loop through all the routes and find the one with the closest match, but then the problem is that it could default to `/` if nothing matched (e.g with the input `/page/1` which really should return no matches, but the closest would be '/')

Comment: escape the backslash...

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a look at how ExpressJS handled route matching, and found that there is a PHP port of the library they use. https://github.com/gpolguere/path-to-regexp-php

Now that I've implemented that everything works as expected :)